# How can I use full join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL table.

### programs

```
id      | sellDate
1       | 2011-05-30
2       | 2011-09-15
3       | 2016-03-04
4       | 2017-05-06
5       | 2018-04-16
```

### activation

```
id      | activation   | program_id
1       | 2011-05-30   | 1
2       | 2011-09-15   | 2
3       | 2016-03-04   | 3
4       | 2017-05-06   | 4
```

The `programs` table contains when a customer buy a program, the `activation` contains when the customer activated it. I want to print that customers where the customer buy the program where the id is 5, but not activate it, so the program id 5 isn't in the activation table. How can I solve this?

Comment: You should be more precise about the information you give. Is the ID in "programs" a PK? Because if you're saving all your sales there, it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM programs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT program_id FROM activation);
```

If you use DBMS that has better JOIN performance:

```
SELECT id FROM programs p LEFT OUTER JOIN activation a ON p.id=a.program_id WHERE a.program_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: We can also use `NOT EXISTS()` in a correlated subquery. You may add that query to the answer as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM programs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT program_id FROM activation);
```